# Cashing in American check in non-supported country

Tags: check

In more and more countries there are no companies dealing with American checks anymore. I'm stuck in one of these unable to travel abroad in the near feature due to the pandemic. How can I cash in my check before it expires? Are there some online services that offer this?

ps. I'm not American, I don't have an American bank account, address or any similar stuff. I only have a check to my name from the US. I've asked around a lot and nobody knows a solution that doesn't involve going abroad. Also note that PayPal has apparently discontinued their service that offered to deposit checks.

Comment: Unfortunately, service/product recommendations are off topic here. That being said, where are you located and have you talked to banks in your home country?

Comment: While not a direct answer to your question, you could reach out to the person or company that wrote you the check and see if they can send you the funds through a different method.  They would be able to stop payment on the check before doing this to prevent the money from being withdrawn from their account twice.

Comment: @Eric Tried without success, so I've given up on that.

Comment: @Nosjack Of course I've tried banks, and other financial institutions as well, none of them could help, or even recommend an option. I'm in Hungary.

Comment: @domotorp Another option you might look into is online check cashing services.  You may be able to take advantage of these if you can get a US bank account number through something like Transferwise Borderless accounts or Revolut.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where the check came from, it might be easier to just ask them to pay you a different way.

If you have a trusted friend who does have an American bank account, you could endorse the check to them, have them cash it, and then pay you through whatever means works in your country. On the back, you write "pay to the order of ____" (your friend's name), and sign it, which will allow them to cash it.

for more info, including some caveats: https://www.mybanktracker.com/checking/faq/sign-check-someone-else-deposit-278325

Comment: I have already tried this and since the sum is over 1000, no banks seem to allow it.